# How can I return a string properly in C

Tags: c, string, function, char, return

I'm having a simple question to make, because I can't really find the way to return a string from a function and put it in another string. My code in C is this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *func();

int main()
{
        char *temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * 25);

        temp = func();
        printf("String received: %s\n", temp);

        return 0;
}

char *func()
{
        char str[25];

        strcpy(str, "HEY THERE!");
        printf("String sent: %s\n", str);

        return str;
}
```

I get this result:
String sent: HEY THERE!
String received:

Any idea how to do it properly? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic memory, yes, but it's used in the wrong place. Think about this code again:

```
char *temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * 25);
temp = func();
```

What you are doing is to allocate some memory for `temp`, and then assign it another value: the return value of `func()`, that's memory leak.

The correct method is to allocate memory in `func()`, and return the pointer to the allocated memory. Remember to free it when it's not used.

Comment: I see what you say @Yu is totally correct. But still try to find the solution, temp seems empty again

Comment: @STRATOSpeed You are now allocating memory for `str`, right? Like `char *str = malloc(25);` ?

Comment: Ok ok Yes @Yu i found it thanks a lot! That was it :)